# How to embed a layout inside another layout?

Tags: java, android, xml, layout

I want a layout similar to below image, where (2) is a LinearLayout and (1) is whatever it can be to make this possible. 
For example imagine (2) is a button configuration and (1) is some text in different sizes and needs to go around (2).

[small square inside (bottom right) big square](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cmqQg.png)

Seems folks misunderstand my question even with the image demonstration, (2) is not on top of (1) !!! Let me add a more detailed image as below:

[embedded not on top of](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qfVJ2.png)

Comment: Is your question "how to wrap text around an image"?

Answer (score 0):

Its pretty easy, Have you done Constraint Layout? try with this.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

   <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="250dp">

      <ImageView
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
          app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
          app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
          app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
          app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


      <ImageView
          android:layout_width="80dp"
          android:layout_height="80dp"
          android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
          app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
          app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
          app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
          app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
          app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
          app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />


   </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>



</LinearLayout>
```

Please try with this code (Paste this code in xml layout file) and get the result. 
Note : You have to define constrains as per given here.

Comment: I have worked with Constraint Layout, but how would you do it? Doesn't have any related option as far a i know.

Comment: Not what i asked at all my friend! i didn't say (2) needs to be on top of (1)!! this can be done with a simple relativelayout too. imagine your first image is text, then your second image should not go on top of text. but text should go around image.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use `include`. Note that if you include `android:id...` into the `<include />` tag, it will override whatever id was defined inside the included layout.  For example:

```
<include
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:id="@+id/some_id_if_needed"
   layout="@layout/yourlayout" />
```

yourlayout.xml:

```
<LinearLayout
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:id="@+id/some_other_id">
   <Button
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:id="@+id/button1" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

Then you would reference this included layout in code as follows:

```
View includedLayout = findViewById(R.id.some_id_if_needed);
Button insideTheIncludedLayout = (Button)includedLayout.findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

Comment: Didn't work at all. I guess you didn't understand my question.